# Is the @ character ever used in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Is there any sort of JavaScript expression aside from that which is inside a String that interprets the @ symbol?

Comment: decorators in ES2016 which is not a standard, as the others have pointed out...

Comment: Not in the current standard.

Comment: @JordanHendrix there are no decorators in the ES2016 (as well as the ES2016 does not exist as a final standard yet).

Comment: @JordanHendrix even when it's finalised - there will be no decorators in it. The feature set for ES2016 is known and it does not include decorators: http://www.2ality.com/2016/01/ecmascript-2016.html

Comment: Aye, Decorators keep getting pushed back, as the parties cannot agree on the actual argument pattern. Seems silly, but once they do agree, I'll bet you they'll probably make it into ES2017, but that's purely speculation.

Comment: Understood, its a proposal, that said, people are talking/blogging/etc about decorators. He could easily run into them online, and that might be the impetus for the question. There is experimentaly functionality that supports using decorators right now and they use the '@'. @Bryan Grace: Take a look here for some examples: https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators

Comment: JsDoc makes use of it in comments.

Comment: `/@/` ain't no string ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The latest actual standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) does not define any special use for the `@` character.